# Convert nat to big_int in extraction of Coq to Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, coq, coq-extraction

I am doing extraction convert `nat` to `big_int`

When I used the library: [ExtrOcamlNatBigInt](http://coq.inria.fr/V8.3/stdlib/Coq.extraction.ExtrOcamlNatBigInt.html), it does not return the correct type for `big_int` in `Ocaml`

So I modify it (the file ExtrOcamlNatBigInt), but I cannot find the way to define function `nat_case` because in the libary `Big_int` of Ocaml they do not have function `nat_case`.

```
Extract Inductive nat => "Big_int.big_int"
  [ "Big_int.zero_big_int" "Big_int.succ_big_int" ] "Big_int.nat_case".
```

I try to define a second definition for `nat_case` by :

```
Extract Inductive nat => "Big_int.big_int"
  [ "Big_int.zero_big_int" "Big_int.succ_big_int" ] "(fun fO fS n ->
    let one = Big_int.unit_big_int in
    if n = Big_int.zero_big_int then fO () else fS (n - one))".
```

Here is a result after using the second definition:

```
(** val nat_rect :
    'a1 -> (Big_int.big_int -> 'a1 -> 'a1) -> Big_int.big_int -> 'a1 **)

let rec nat_rect f f0 n =
  let one = Big_int.unit_big_int in
    if n = Big_int.zero_big_int then f () else f0 (n - one)
    (fun _ ->
    f)
    (fun n0 ->
    f0 n0 (nat_rect f f0 n0)) n
```

I got an error at `n` of line `else f0 (n - one)`:

**File "Datatypes.ml", line 68, characters 51-52: Error: This expression has type Big_int.big_int but an expression was expected of type int**

I think it is because of the `minus` (`-`)

I also modify the `minus` extraction :

```
Extract Constant minus => "fun n m -> Big_int.max_big_int Big_int.zero_big_int 
   (Big_int.sub_big_int n m)".
```

Could you please help me to define the function `nat_case` for `Big_int`? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(-)` is reserved to integer operation, you can't use the same operator for `big_int`. Replace

```
(n - one)
```

by :

```
Big_int.sub_big_int n one
```